# How to extract lists from a list of lists

Tags: java

I have the following list of lists:

```
    List<List<Integer>> fronts = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> f0 = new ArrayList<>();
    f0.add(0);
    f0.add(1);
    f0.add(2);
    f0.add(3);
    fronts.add(f0);

    List<Integer> f1 = new ArrayList<>();
    f1.add(6);
    f1.add(7);
    f1.add(8);
    f1.add(9);
    fronts.add(f1);

    List<Integer> f2 = new ArrayList<>();
    f2.add(10);
    f2.add(11);
    f2.add(12);
    f2.add(13);
    fronts.add(f2);
```

I would like to get four lists where the first list contains the first element of each list such that `0,6,10` and the second list is `1,7,11` and so on.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort toward solving this yourself?

Comment: Step 1: ask on Stack Overflow, step 2: receive downvotes, step 3: delete question, step 4: attempt the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list containing the required 4 lists.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> fronts = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> f0 = new ArrayList<>();
        f0.add(0);
        f0.add(1);
        f0.add(2);
        f0.add(3);
        fronts.add(f0);

        List<Integer> f1 = new ArrayList<>();
        f1.add(6);
        f1.add(7);
        f1.add(8);
        f1.add(9);
        fronts.add(f1);

        List<Integer> f2 = new ArrayList<>();
        f2.add(10);
        f2.add(11);
        f2.add(12);
        f2.add(13);
        fronts.add(f2);

        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fronts.get(0).size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int j = 0; j < fronts.size(); j++) {
                temp.add(fronts.get(j).get(i));
            }
            result.add(temp);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 6, 10], [1, 7, 11], [2, 8, 12], [3, 9, 13]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
for(int i=0; i<fronts.get(0).size();i++){
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int j=0; j<fronts.size();j++){
        newList.add(fronts.get(j).get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(newList);
}
```

Comment: How is it different from the solution which I've already posted?

Comment: When I started working on this question no answer was there.While I was posting my ans I have not noticed that urs one was there.

Comment: No worries; keep contributing. Wish you all the best!